# 5 days alone in Malaysia - what should I do?

Tags: malaysia

So I'm landing in KL, going to spend 3-4 days drinking and partying etc. with some friends.

Then I got about 5 days alone to do whatever I want before flying from Penang. Kind of an awkward number of days as I'm not sure whether I should just spend it all in Penang or pick one more place before hitting Penang.

Where should I go? I'm probably going to be pretty partied out by then so not looking to do more drinking. I'm not a big sightseeing type person unless it's something really spectacular and I enjoy outdoor activities.

Comment: This is likely to be closed as too broad.  Are there specific things that interest you, as opposed to do not interest you?

Comment: If you have that much time, perhaps you should use the typical web sites to meet *cough* friends - it's great to meet new people whether expats or locals for a coffee or sandwich.  Who knows, you may meet your future spouse. Bon chance!

Answer (score 2):

Having visited Malaysia a few times, here are things in my bucket list that you can try out; they are all easily serviced in 5 days thanks to great transportation infrastructure in Malaysia.

To start off with, as you are in Penang, there is plenty to do there from shopping to beaches and then there is the botanical gardens as well.

You can take a ferry to [Langkawi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langkawi) which has great beaches an epic sky bridge above the forest.

Other destinations:

- [Genting Highlands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genting_Highlands). This is a resort near KL (1/1.5 hours by car), or take a cable car and is way up in the mountains (5,710 ft). Great if you are into casinos. Try sipping a latte at the Starbucks with clouds literally at your feet.
- [Cameron Highlands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cameron_Highlands#Landmarks_and_tourism). You can find great large vasts of tea plantations and great nature trails here. You did not say when you were going to be in Malaysia, so if you decide to go to Cameron Highlands make sure you check the weather first and what trails are available. If you are into nature photography this is also a great option.

Comment: As addition Landkawi Sky Bridge closed on reconstracton. Malasian authorities promise it will open December'14.